# Display domain user full name on lock screen

Tags: windows-7

By default the Windows 7 lock screen displays to username in the format 'DOMAIN\USERNAME'. Because in this company the username is just a three letter abbreviation, we would like to display the full name in the lock screen (just like in the start menu).

Does anyone know if this is even possible? I could not find a GPO setting or anything related on Google.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the info reading this http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/182700-lock-computer-screen-display-user-information-not.html and you could deploy via GPO if you have a lot of machines.